# autogenerated primary keys in postgres with jooq

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I am using jooq generated dao's to do a create operation on a table.
The table has a primary key 'id' with type bigserial and the default constraints of not null

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.book (
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  author varchar(64)
  CONSTRAINT book_primary PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

to create a record with jooq i say

```java
Book b = new Book();
b.setAuthor("Eric");
BookDao bd = new BookDao(jooqConfiguration);
bd.insert(b);
```

This throws a constrain violation exception that id is null.If i set an id such as

```java
Book b = new Book();
b.setId(25);
b.setAuthor("Eric");
BookDao bd = new BookDao(jooqConfiguration);
bd.insert(b);
```

I do not get the exception but postgres does not generate a value automatically.

The postgres documentation at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL says  the "Omit the SERIAL column in INSERT, or specify DEFAULT keyword"

How do i configure the jooq generated dao to either omit this column or use a value of DEFAULT

Edit - I am using jooq version 3.3.2 and postgres 8.4. ( The final target is aws redshift. So prototyping on postgres 8.4).

Comment: Just a side note: your link is not "the postgres documentation". The official manual is here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html

Comment: Just to be sure, you *are* using the latest jOOQ version (3.4.0)?

Comment: Use nextval(), check the manual: http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual-single-page/#sequences-and-serials

Comment: @FrankHeikens - this would mean 2 calls to the db for each object created and this has to be done for multiple objects. Is there no way of telling jooq that the db would generate the required value?

Comment: @LukasEder - I am using jooq version 3.3.2 which is the latest on mvn repository and postgres 8.4.Should i move to jooq 3.4.0?  The final target is aws redshift.So prototyping on postgres 8.4.

Comment: You don't need 2 calls, you can use nextval() inside the values. Just check the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue of generated dao's not properly handling handling default values is already present in jooq's list of github issues as https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2700.

It is fixed in 3.4.0. Migrating to 3.4.0 fixed the issue for me.

answering the question so that other can find it if required.

Comment: You were faster than me :-) But I thought that there was an issue somewhere, thanks for looking it up